# jsPDF convert html to pdf: utf-8 works only with text, but not html

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I need to convert html to pdf with jsPDF.
It contains UTF-8 symbols (cyrillic).
I used fontconverter to generate js-file for my custom font as written here:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

So now example with text works like a charm.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
doc.setFont('PTSans');
doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text("А ну чики брики и в дамки!", 10, 10);
```

And example with html ignores my custom font and exports incorrect symbols.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
doc.setFont('PTSans');
doc.setFontSize(10);
pdf.html( "<html>А ну чики брики и в дамки!</html>", { callback: function (pdf) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:500px');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
    }
});
```

What I need to do to export html to pdf with unicode symbols?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Is it being served with the correct charset?

Comment: I try both "А ну чики брики и в дамки!", and "<html>А ну чики брики и в дамки!</html>". How should I provide charset?

Comment: You changed the question. It doesn't work with the HTML in the string instead of `document.body` either? Are you using a webserver? Make sure the HTTP header `Content-type` contains the charset for all files (HTML and JavaScript). Otherwise set metatags in the HTML. See: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en

Comment: @RoToRa, thanks for the answer. It doesn't work with `document.body` nor with `<html>А ну чики брики и в дамки!</html>`
It also doesn't work if I provide charset: `<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head>А ну чики брики и в дамки!</html> `

Comment: I even tried this - but the same result
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>А ну чики брики и в дамки!</html>`

Comment: Sorry, then I can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found how to solve this problem and created issue on jspdf github.
And I've found that pdfmake.org correctly works with utf-8 symbols, so if you have same problems, use pdfmake.

Comment: I have the same problem